# flutter build apk error with gradle exit code 1

Tags: flutter

When I run flutter build apk -v, I see the following output:

```
[   +1 ms]          *********************************************************
[        ] WARNING: This version of shared_preferences will break your Android build if it or its
dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
[   +1 ms]          See ---(google url)--- for more information on the problem and how to fix it.[   +1 ms]          This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the
error may be unrelated.
[   +5 ms]          *********************************************************
[   +7 ms] 197 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 190 up-to-date
[ +370 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... (completed in 46.8s)
[   +5 ms] "flutter apk" took 53,500ms.
[        ] "flutter apk" took 53,500ms.
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:507:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:346:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/apk.dart:34:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      BuildApkCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:79:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:478:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:383:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#10     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#11     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#12     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:375:20)
#14     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:396:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#18     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#19     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#20     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#21     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#22     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:356:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#23     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:25)
#24     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
#25     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:14)
#26     FlutterCommandRunner.run
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:242:18)
#27     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#30     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#31     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1500:12)
#32     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:60:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#33     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#34     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#35     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#36     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#37     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#38     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#39     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:56:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#40     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:51:10)
#41     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:62:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#42     main (file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#43     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#44     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

When I change (android\app)build.gradle like this, the same output is shown.

```
  signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }

   }
```

I think androidx has a problem but I don't know what to do.
  I tried  to migrate androidx, the first time I succeeded but when I tried once again they said No Usages Found in the Project, so I am not able to do it one more time

Additional Information :
I used android studio, and I upgraded everything. gradle, sdkversion(to 29) distrubuturl(to 5.4.1) and also added android.useAndroidx  = true